# How to add third party library in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to figure out how to install this library called *"Pngwriter"*. It has instructions on how to install it but I don't really understand as I am new to this.

Im using *Windows 8.1*, It's a  *C++* directory and *VS 2015*

The instructions are:

The preferred way to install PNGwriter is using `CMake`:

- `git clone https://github.com/pngwriter/pngwriter.git`
- `mkdir -p build && cd build`
- `cmake ../pngwriter`
- `make install` (creates the libs in `lib/` and a `pngwriter.h` in `include/`)

But I am not sure where I am supposed to enter this text ^^^. It doesn't run in the command prompt so...? Where do I run it?

Comment: At your Linux command prompt. Those are not Windows commands.

Comment: Semi good-ish luck with those instructions. Easy as pie on linux, bit not so easy on Windows which won't have all the needed tools installed by default (or easily installed after the fact).

Comment: Oh :| so how do i this on windows?

Comment: PNG witrer page says this: http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/main-en.php#windows and links to this: http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/howto_msvc.php

Comment: You can always try Cygwin

Comment: Cygwin and MSVC don't generally mesh well. It's a possibility, but a last resort.

Comment: Read _all_ the documentation, not just the first page you find. There are Windows installation instructions there too. -1 for no research, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: (from the PNGwriter documentation)

**How do I use PNGwriter under Windows?**

---

> Please note: Though there are guides on this site for compiling PNGwriter under Windows using some popular compilers, I cannot offer support for this task.
>   You should get hold of a Windows implementation of GCC, the free GNU C/C++ compiler (two possible ways to do this are [www.mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org/) and [www.cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/)). You can also use the Borland C++ Builder or Microsoft Visual C++ .NET on Windows XP. Here are two clear, step-by-step HowTos: [" Setting Up PNGWriter for Borland C++ Builder Version 6 on Windows XP"](http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/howto_borland.php) and ["Setting Up PNGWriter for Microsoft Visual C++ .NET on Windows XP"](http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/howto_msvc.php).
>   Also, using PNGwriter with Bloodshed Dev C++ is quite easy, as pointed out by Siva Chandra: "You can download the pre-compiled libraries for freetype from the GnuWin32 web-site: [gnuwin32.sf.net](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). To build PNGwriter itself, create a new C++ library project called libpngwriter. Include the PNGwriter header file and the implementation file into this new project. Then compile. And thats it. You will have a libpngwriter.a file ready for use. Note that this will by default assume availability of freetype. To remove such assumption, you will have to compile with this option: -DNO_FREETYPE".
>   **Please note:** pngwriter.cc has to be renamed to pngwiter.cpp for MSVC7. If the extension is not changed then the C/C++ folder for the project property does not become visible and hence the MSVC7's default of using compiled headers in its project build will always return an error about being unable to find some precompiled header. It is necessary to change that feature in the project property in order to successfully build the PNGwriter library using this compiler.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either windows cmd or cygwin, but first, you need to download a few tools.

You have to download this tool: https://git-scm.com/ in order to use the first comand 'git'. This is used to download the github directory.

Then you have to download this: http://www.cmake.org/ to use the cmake comand.

And this http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm to use the make comand.

Also, make sure you add the path of each one of this programs to your PATH enviroment variable.